# Should I make my server bind to 0.0.0.0 on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have a simple app which I can either bind so that only localhost can access it, or to 0.0.0.0 so anyone on the network can access it. I know how this works in practice, and the security implications of it, on a local network. Is Heroku different? Does their reverse proxy listen from localhost on a dyno such that I can bind to 127.0.0.1 safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From experience, I can say that you do bind to 0.0.0.0.

For the port, you use the environment variable for `PORT`.